# ReactJS update data in component when user is logged in

Tags: reactjs

I have dashboard which should show data if a user is logged in and other data if no user is logged in. I already managed to figure out if a user is logged in it is not reflected on the page. It only changes after reloading the page.

This is what I have: An Account object with a `userstatus` component to hold details of the user. The Account object is placed in a context that is wrapped in the `App.js`. It also has a `getSession` function which gets the user details from the authentication mechanism. `getSession` also updates the userstatus according to the result (logged_in or not_logged_in). Second I have a dashboard component which runs the `getSession` method and puts the result in the console. Everythings fine. But the `render` function did not get the changed `userstatus`.

This is my code (Accounts.js):

```
export const AccountContext = createContext();

export const Account = {

  userstatus: {
    loggedinStatus: "not_logged_in",
    values: {},
    touched: {},
    errors: {}
  },

  getSession: async () =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ...

      }
    }),
}
```

This is the Dashboard.js:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState();
  const { getSession, userstatus } = useContext(AccountContext);

  getSession()
    .then(session => {
      console.log('Dashboard Session:', session);
      userstatus.loggedinStatus = "logged_in"
      setStatus(1)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('No Session found.');
      userstatus.loggedinStatus = "not_logged_in"
      setStatus(0);
    });
  
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {userstatus.loggedinStatus}
      {status}
      {userstatus.loggedinStatus === "logged_in" ? 'User logged in': 'not logged in'}
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={4}
      ...
```

I already tried with `useState` and `useEffect`, both without luck. The `userstatus` seems to be the most logical, however, it does not update automatically. How can I reflect the current state in the Dashboard (and other components)?

Answer (score 0):

1. React only re-renders component when any state change occur.
2. `userstatus` is simply a variable whose changes does not reflect for react. Either you should use `userstatus`as your app state or you can pass it in `CreateContext` and then use reducers for update. Once any of two ways you use, you would see react's render function reflect the changes in `userstatus`.

For how to use Context API, [refer docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: OK, I thought it is already part of the context. When it is just a variable, how can I make it the app state? `useState` in `Accounts.js` did not work?

Comment: You can define state in App.js using `useState` and then pass a function defined inside the parent component to the child which will be used to update `userStatusState`